# Is there a language with RAII + Ref counting that does not have unsafe pointer arithmetric?

Tags: c++, memory, programming-languages, raii

RAII = Resource Acquisition is Initialization

Ref Counting = "poor man's GC"

Together, they are quite powerful (like a ref-counted 3D object holding a VBO, which it throws frees when it's destructor is called).

Now, question is -- does RAII exist in any langauge besides C++? In particular, a language that does not allow pointer arithmetric / buffer overflows?

Comment: Ref counting isn't a poor man's GC; GC is a lazy man's ref counting

Comment: Why is reference-counting part of the question?  If a language supports RAII, why wouldn't one be able to write their own reference-counting, smart-pointer-like classes?

Comment: @Terry: Not at all. GC is more efficient and more robust (handles cycles). I'm all for RAII and you can get pretty far with ref counting, but let's not deceive ourselves.

Comment: Apart from that, C++ *does not allow "unsafe buffer arithmetics" or buffer overflows. Both are undefined behavior. The problem with C++ is merely that the compiler is unable to catch it if you violate the rules.

Comment: If anything, ref counting is a rich man's GC. You have to be pretty rich, to spend all that extra programmer time, code complexity, and CPU cycles, solving a problem which GC would do cheaper ;-)

Comment: @jalf - I think it's pretty obvious what the question means. You interpret "allow" as the opposite of "forbid", but it is also the opposite of "prevent". C++ "allows" unsafe pointer operations in the same sense that leaving all your doors and windows unlocked "allows" burglars into the house. Sure, it's forbidden, but that doesn't actually prevent it, because burglars will burgle, and programmers will make errors.

Comment: @jalf: This probably isn't the write forum for this debate, but you're fooling yourself if you think those are universally accepted facts. Robustness is debatable, but I loled@GC being more efficient.

Comment: @Terry: Lol all you want. Perhaps you should read a book instead. The amortized cost of tracking and deleting objects is **huge** for refcounting vs a GC. Do the math. A ref counter has to be updated whenever a reference is created or removed. It has to be done in a thread-safe manner which costs extra. A GC has *zero* overhead for that, and just needs to traverse the tree of live objects every once in a while. Refcounting is just ridiculously costly. I'm sorry to burst your bubble. But sometimes, even a C++ programmer has to face facts.

Comment: How is robustness "debatable"? A GC handles whatever you throw at it, refcounting falls over the moment you introduce a cycle. What I said might not be "unviersally accepted", but they sure are facts. That you haven't done the research necessary to *face* facts is hardly my problem.
@Steve: Yes, I agree. I simply wanted to clarify that these illegal operations are not part of the C++ language. The language just doesn't prevent them from occurring.

Comment: @jalf, I like how you casually mention "...and just needs to traverse the tree of live objects every once in a while" like it's no big deal. Another lol, thx.

Comment: @Terry: Yes, it typically isn't a big deal. Because it has to be done so rarely, and because most objects are *not* live, so they have literally zero cost. I'm glad you're so easy to amuse. Reading a book on compilers would crack you up, I think.

Comment: -1 to me for feeding the trolls, but I'll wrap it up. This debate is uninteresting @jalf, and hasn't been for about 10 years. You have nothing new to add. I've personally concluded that both GC schemes and  refcounting schemes have advantages and disadvantages and are appropriate at different times. If you don't understand the drawbacks of "stop the world to GC", the memory bloat, or indeterminate destructions semantics of a GC system are undesirable in some cases, then it's not my job to educate you. A lot about this has been written elsewhere. Check a few of those books you have so many of.

Comment: @Terry: Thanks, now you gave me a good lol. I'm glad you've personally concluded whatever your preconceptions said. Saves you all the bother of learning new things. Of course they both have advantages and disadvantages, and I never pretended that the specific drawbacks you mention did not exist. That was not the issue. The issue was your claim that refcounting is *more efficient* than a GC. Which it is not. trying to change the subject and pretend that it was really about nondeterministic destruction is just sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl 5 has ref counting and destructors that are guaranteed to be called when all references fall out of scope, so RAII is available in the language, although most Perl programmers don't use the term.

And Perl 5 does not expose raw pointers to Perl code.

Perl 6, however, has a real garbage collector, and in fact allows the garbage collector to be switched out; so you can't rely on things being collected in any particular order.

I believe Python and Lua use reference counting.

Comment: CPython uses reference counting plus an optional cycle-detecting garbage collector.  Jython and IronPython use the underlying platform's garbage collectors, which are not reference-count based.

Answer (score 3):

D has RAII but still has pointer arithmetic :( BUT, you don't really have to use it. Please note getting D to work was a pain in the butt for me so IM JUST SAYING.

Comment: D's "safe mode" has *no* pointer arithmetic. What it really lacks is Ref counting. It only has rich man's GC :p.

Answer (score 3):

While not exactly RAII, Python has the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) and C# has the [using statement.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Those are exactly what RAII is not: they put the burden on the caller (ie everywhere) rather than the callee (written once for all).

Comment: @Matthieu - I agree that they put the burden on the caller.  But to me they still feel RAII-like as they have the property that uninitialization does not require a separate call.

Answer (score 2):

perl, python (C), php, and tcl are reference counted and have mechanisms to destroy an object once its reference count goes to zero, which can happen as soon as a variable goes out of scope. built-in types are released automatically. user-defined classes have a way to define a destructor that will get called upon release.

there are some edge cases: global variables might not be released until the end and circular references may not be released until the end (though php has recently implemented a gc that handles this case and python 2 added a cycle detector).

Answer (score 2):

Python (the standard CPython, not variants like Jython, Unladen Swallow and IronPython) uses reference counting for its objects.

With that, it also has RAII and (mostly) deterministic garbage collection.  For example, this is supposed to work deterministically closing files:

```
def a():
   fp = open('/my/file', 'r')
   return fp.read()
```

Note `fp.close()` is never called. As soon as `fp` goes out of scope, the object *should* be destroyed. However, there are some cases where deterministic finalization is not guaranteed, such as in:

- Something throws an exception and the traceback is currently being handled, or a reference is kept to it (note `sys.last_traceback` keeps the last traceback)
- Cyclic references exist in an object, causing the reference count to not go to zero

Therefore, while python theoretically has deterministic finalization, it is better to explicitly close any resources where it's possible an exception (like IOError or the like) could cause the object to remain live.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write `with open('/my/file', 'r') as fp: return fp.read()`?

Comment: As discussed in the other python answer, that's not RAII; it's just syntactic sugar for a try/finally that closes it. But yes, it's better python in that you will close the file even in exception conditions, assuming you're running python 2.6+ or 2.5 with the `__future__.with_statement` imported.  Also, this will work for garbage-collected pythons such as Jython/Unladen Swallow/IronPython

Answer (score 1):

[Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala)'s memory management of objects is based on reference counting, and it has RAII (in the sense that it's destructors are called deterministically). The typical use case is to create GUIs, where the overhead from refcounting is often negligible. You can use pointers and bypass the refcounting, for example for interoperability, or if you need the extra performance, but in most cases you can live without pointers. It also does something clever, you can mark references as `owned` or `unowned` and transfer ownership, and in many cases it is able to elide the reference counting (if an object does not escape a function, for example). Vala is closely connected to GObject/GTK, so it only makes sense to use if you want to work in that ecosystem.

Another interesting candidate would be [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/). While it also has pointers and garbage collection, both are optional. You can write programs completely with an equivalent of C++'s smart pointers, with guaranteed no leaks, and it supports RAII. It also has a concept of reference ownership, like Vala, but a bit more complex. Essentially, Rust gives you complete control over how you manage memory. You can work at the bare metal level, and could even write a kernel in it, or you can work at a high level with a GC, or anything in between, and most of the time it protects you from leaking memory or other pointer-related bugs. The downside is that it is pretty complex, and since it is still in development things might change.